# threads created by ThreadPoolExecutor keeps running after shutdown

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I am trying to apply the priciple of Multithread producer/consumer of some datas using two threadPoolExecutors, i noticed that everything works fine but the program refuse to shut down and some threads are still running after shutting down the 2 threadPools:

In main class:

```
ExecutorService executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 10, 40, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
        new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(edmsIds.size()));
ExecutorService consumerExecutor =  new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 10, 0L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(edmsIds.size()));for(
String edmsID:edmsIds)

{

    Runnable worker = new BatchWorkerThread(resumeFile, stratrKeysToUpdate, xslFiles, errorThrown, edmsID,
            consumerExecutor, edmsIds.size(), executor);
    executor.execute(worker);
}
```

In producer Class:

```
while (edmsNumber > 0) {
    Runnable consumer = new ConsumerThread(brokerWorker);
    consumExecutor.execute(consumer);//decreasing the edmsNumber

}
if (edmsNumber < 1) {
    prodExecutor.shutdownNow();
    consumExecutor.shutdownNow();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

See the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow()):

> There are **no guarantees** beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing
>   actively executing tasks. For example, typical implementations will
>   cancel via Thread.interrupt(), so any task that fails to respond to
>   interrupts may never terminate.

If the running task is not interruptable(does not respond to interrupt singal), it will continue execute.

Answer (score 1):

Actually i wanted to post the cause of the problem and the solution :

---

- Cause

  i was trying to shutdown the excutor while it is not terminated yet.
- Solution

  shut it down only after its termination using a simple code.

For example :

`prodExecutor.shutdownNow();
while (!prodExecutor.isTerminated()) {}`

- Another solution is to use ExecutorCompletionService  if you want to take tasks as they complete you need an ExecutorCompletionService. This acts as a BlockingQueue that will allow you to poll for tasks as and when they finish.